# Filtering ember model in router

Tags: ember.js, filter, model, store

I'm trying to return the model store into my template but before I do the return I would like to filter by a certain property, returning only those records that have that property. Also, in my model, I'm overriding the default 'id' with a serializer.

In my console I'm getting a "store is not defined ReferenceError: store is not defined" Any ideas ?

Here's my route:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default Ember.Route.extend({

    model: function() {

    return this.store.find('link').then(function(links) {
        return store.filter('link', { linkTypeCode: 'NSL' });

    });

    }

});
```

Model:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    artifactId : DS.attr('number'),
    artifactName : DS.attr('string'),
    linkTypeCode : DS.attr('string')
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your route is calling `store` instead of `this.store`.  Since this is within an asynchronous callback, `this.store` will also need to have been cached to a variable.

Additionally, once you fix this you will encounter an error with your filter.  The filter expects a function.

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default Ember.Route.extend({

  model: function() {
    var Store = this.store;

    return Store.find('link').then(function(links) {
      return Store.filter('link', function (record) { 
        return record.get('linkTypeCode') === 'NSL'; 
      });
    });
  }

});
```

I would also note that `DS.filter` returns a live record array, meaning it's records are always kept up-to-date with the records the store learns about.  It would be possible to do the following.

```
Store.find('link');
return Store.filter('link', function (record) {
  return record.get('linkTypeCode') === 'NSL';
});
```

Comment: This answer, and specially the snippet at the bottom, deserves many more upvotes.

Comment: this implies that my `adapter` has to implement `find` and `filter`, right?