# Filtering store data in ember

Tags: ember.js, filter, ember-data

I am trying to filter some hard coded data in an Ember route which is being provided by mirage and having trouble.

Either Ember moans at my syntax (when trying to use `filter` on the store) or it doesn't return any data when I use `findAll` and then use the JS filter method on the objects.

***Attempt 1 - Using findAll():***

**Route**

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model() {
        return {
            txSites: this.get('store').findAll('site').filter((site) => {
                return site.siteType === 'tx'; 
            })
        };
    }
});
```

**Template**

```
            <select class="form-control">
                {{#each model.txSites as |site|}}
                    <option value="{{site.id}}">{{site.name}}</option>
                {{/each}}
            </select>
```

**Mirage endpoint**

```
this.get('/sites', () => {    

 return {
     data: [{
         type: 'site',
         id: 1,
         attributes: {
             name: 'London',
             siteType: 'tx'
         }
     },
     {
         type: 'site',
         id: 2,
         attributes: {
             name: 'Bristol',
             siteType: 'rx'                 
         }
     }]
  }      
});
```

**Result**

Successful request: GET /sites
Object {data: Array[2]}

But nothing bound to the dropdown (other calls where I'm not trying to filter the results work ok).

***Attempt #2 : Using `filter`:***

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model() {
        return {
            txSites: this.get('store').filter('site', (site) => {
                return site.siteType === 'tx'; 
            })
        };
    }
});
```

**Result**

No call made to API

***Attempt #3 : using filter***

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model() {
        return {
            txSites: this.get('store').filter('site', { siteType: 'tx' }, (site) => {
                return site.siteType === 'tx'; 
            }).then((results) => { return results })
        };
    }
});
```

**Result**

Successful request: GET /sites?siteType=tx
Object {data: Array[2]}

But no data bound to the select item.

It feels like I'm missing something basic here. Using ember 2.5 and ember data 1.13.

Is there a recommended way to approach this?

**EDIT:**

**Attempt #4 - findAll with RSVP hash:**

**Route**

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model() {
        return Ember.RSVP.hash({
            oneThing: this.store.findAll('oneThing'),
            anotherThing: this.store.findAll('anotherThing'),
            txSites: this.store.findAll('site').filter((site) => {
                console.log(site);
                return site.siteType === 'tx';
            })
        });
    }
});
```

**Result**

Both the calls to `oneThing` and `anotherThing` bind ok, but `txSites` does not.

As a further test I removed the `.filter` from the `txSites` property and this happily returns the whole dataset and binds ok (so I'm happy that it's the filter causing the problem and the binding is ok).

**Attempt #5**

**Route**

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model() {
        return Ember.RSVP.hash({
            oneThing: this.store.findAll('oneThing'),
            anotherThing: this.store.findAll('anotherThing'),
            txSites: this.store.findAll('site')
                 .then(results => results.filter((site) => {
                    return site.siteType === 'tx'; 
                 }))
        });
    }
});
```

**Result**

No data returned, console logging the `site` inside the filter seems to be a promise not the result of the resolved promise.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should just filter after the 'findAll' promise resolves, like this:

```
model() {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
        oneThing: this.store.findAll('oneThing'),
        anotherThing: this.store.findAll('anotherThing'),
        txSites: this.store.findAll('site')
                 .then(results => results.filter((site) => {
                    return site.get('siteType') === 'tx'; 
                 });
    });
}
```

**Also in the mirage you should use dasherized values, so 'site-type' instead of siteType.**

Comment: Hi Igor, I've tried the above code to no avail I'm afraid. It just returns me nothing. 
If I console.log the `site` in the above code I get what I presume is an ember promise (not the site itself) I've attached this to the original question

Comment: You tired this exact code, or you are talking about your attempt #4? Because they are not the same.

Comment: On attempt 5 which I added, that is literally copied and pasted from your version.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I didn't see the attempt #5. My code is wrong... youd should to `return site.get('siteType') === 'tx'; `

Comment: You acctaully have your ember "site" object there, but cant access properties directly, since its not a regular JSON object, soyou should use get() instead

Comment: Yeah this is the bit which is odd, logging the `siteType` returns undefined, but you can see from the mirage endpoint that it should be in there.

I'm beginning to think Ember can't handle the ES6 array `.filter()` function how I'm expecting it to, because if I just do `return true` from the body of `filter` it returns both records. It's just not allowing me to hit properties on the `site` object until it gets into the view (I know this because they bind ok)

Comment: Did you do the fix with the `get()` method?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113932/discussion-between-igor-and-dougajmcdonald).

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning data from your model function right. Do it like this.

```
model(){
    return this.get('store').findAll('site').filter((site) => {
        return site.siteType === 'tx';
    });
}
```

Then use it in the template as:

```
{{#each model as |site|}}
```

Update:

I would suggest you to query store instead:

```
this.store.query('site', { filter: { siteType: 'tx' } });
```

Update2:

You can filter txSites inside `afterModel` hook, there all promises from the model hook will be resolved.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback:

#1 I've seen lots of examples calling filter on a store. Infact the page you linked says: "Note: When creating a new record using any of the above methods Ember Data will update DS.RecordArrays such as those returned by store#peekAll(), store#findAll() or store#filter()".

#2. What if I want several properties on my model? I already have two properties which work fine as properties of the object returned from the `model()` hook, it's just the filter version which doesn't work.

Comment: If you want several properties on model then you should return Ember.RSVP.hash, and define in it what properties do you want. Check it here under multiple models. https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.1.0/routing/specifying-a-routes-model/

Comment: Thanks for the RSVP hash link, my model looked the same but just without being wrapped in a hash. 

As a test I removed the `.filter()` from the end of my findAll() call and it returns the entire collection fine, but adding filter returns nothing :/

Comment: Maybe you should use query on store,
https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.0.0/models/finding-records/
 or check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28977099/filtering-ember-model-in-router

Comment: Store returns promise and it must be resolved before you use filter on it, I just realised that my answer is no good.

Comment: I did some checking about and also found `findAll` returning a promise. I guess Ember does some resolving on its own as if I return the `findAll` it resolves the promise itself. I can also call `this.store.findAll('site').then(('results') => {return results; }); and it's ok, it's just I can't seem to intercept the promise at the right point to filter the data

Comment: @dougajmcdonald I updated my answer. Maybe you can try it with query. Did you check second link I sent you, that seems to be solution for this.

Comment: I did try with query as well, this changes the request to my end point but the issues is still the same. In that, if I'm not doing the filtering on the server the results are still wrapped in promises and I can't find the right entry point to apply the filter.

I can possibly look at applying the filter on the server but mirage threw me a few errors about unmapped routes when tried to setup some a parametised routes.

Comment: One more thing, you can try filtering inside afterModel hook, all promises from model hook will be resolved there, so it should work. You just need to pass model to afterModel hook like this: afterModel(model){} and inside do something like: model.filteredSites = model.txSites.filter ....