# Ember get filtered data from the store/mirage

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli-mirage

I am trying to build an app for smarthome devices with ember. I already have installed mirage and declare an array which is called data. It holds arrays like households, users and devices. Now I am stuck with get filtered data from the store and i am really confused by the behaviour of the store. For this reason I already read some equal topics like this [Filtering store data in ember](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37658159/filtering-store-data-in-ember) but this doesn´t work in my case.

Actually this is my router.js

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('about');
  this.route('users', function() {
  });
  this.route('households', function() {
    this.route('index', { path: '/:user_id' })
    this.route('rooms',{ path: '/:household_id' });
    this.route('devices');
  });
});
```

If I am going to households.index I want to see all households which have the user-id in his member-array. The following code snipped shows an example of my data-structure.

```
  "users": [
      {
          "id":101,
          "forename":"Peter",
          "surname":"Peterson",
          "memberIn":[
              501
          ]
      },
      {
          "id":102,
          "forename":"Anna",
          "surname":"Peterson",
          "memberIn":[
              501
          ]
      }
]

  "households":[
      {
          "id":501,
          "name":"Zuhause",
          "admin":131000,
          "member":[
              101,
              102
          ]
}
```

I am calling the route household.index like this {{#link-to "households.index" user.id}} and my route in household.index looks like this

```
model(params) {
    //holt alle Haushalte und gibt dann nur die Haushalte weiter, die auch den aktuellen Benutzer als Member haben.
   return this.get('store').findAll('household').then(results => results.filter((site) => {
       return site.get('member').filter(x => x == params.user_id).length > 0;
   }));
  }
```

And my config.js part at mirage like this:

```
  this.get('/households', function(db, request) {
    return { households: data.households };   
});
```

This works fine!
But in my opinion the server is responsible for giving me the data I am requesting for. So all I want is that I send a specific request and just get the households that I need.

**My attempt:** 
index.js:

```
export default Route.extend({
    model(params) {
        return this.get('store').find('household', params.user_id);
      }
});
```

config js part:

```
  this.get('/households/:id', function(db, request) {
      console.log('household get');
      console.log(data.households.filter(x => x.member.filter(x => x == request.params.id).length > 0));
    return  { households: data.households.filter(x => x.member.filter(x => x == request.params.id).length > 0) };   
});
```

Debug Error:

> Error while processing route: households.index payload.data is null

I cant understand why this error occurs. The log gives me the array i want to return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are using RestSerializer in mirage,

```
// mirage/serializers/application.js
import { RestSerializer } from 'ember-cli-mirage';

export default RestSerializer;
```

and for the right format refer [RESTAdapterAPI](https://emberjs.com/api/ember-data/2.14/classes/DS.RESTAdapter).

Just ensure are you returning data in the below format,

for the single response,

```
{
  "posts": {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "I'm Running to Reform the W3C's Tag",
    "author": "Yehuda Katz"
  }
}
```

and for more than one,

```
{
  "posts": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "I'm Running to Reform the W3C's Tag",
      "author": "Yehuda Katz"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "Rails is omakase",
      "author": "D2H"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default Ember Data ships with the `JSONAPISerializer` and this assumes a few things about the way your server (in this case mirage) is formatting data. In this case the document that mirage is returning is expected to generally conform to the [JSON API Spec](http://jsonapi.org/format/) and have a top-level member `data` where the response's primary data resides.

If you're looking to stick to your custom formatted responses you may want to check out the Ember Data's [JSONSerializer](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember-data/2.16/classes/DS.JSONSerializer). Otherwise, returning the following should get you closer:

```
return  { data: db.households.filter(x => x.member.filter(x => x == request.params.id).length > 0) };
```

or you could leverage the `JSONAPISerializer` that ships with [Mirage](http://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/docs/v0.3.x/serializers/)

See more here [Ember Guides | Serializers](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.17.0/models/customizing-serializers/#toc_jsonapiserializer-conventions)

Comment: thank you for your help. I forget to say that i am using the Restadapter.